# how can avoid this little callback hell

Tags: angularjs, callback, angular-promise

how can avoid this little callback hell?. this code is working fine

```
        estaElServicioDespachado(15).then(function(){
            sePermiteModificarElCupon(25).then(function(respuesta){
                $state.go("barra.general.formularioCupon");
            },function(error){                   
                alert(error);
            })
        },
        function(error){               
            alert(error);
        });
```

I tried to do something like this to avoid the callback hell, but the catch function its not called when 'sepermitemodificarElcupon' rejects

```
    estaElServicioDespachado(15)
        .then(sePermiteModificarElCupon(25)}
        .then(function(){$state.go("barra.general.formularioCupon");})
        )
        .catch(function(error){               
            alert(error);
        })
```

maybe this can help. this are functions that calls a service function that returns promises

```
    function estaElServicioDespachado (id_servicio){
        return catalogoServicios.estaElServicioDespachado(id_servicio)
    }


    function sePermiteModificarElCupon(id_cupon){
        return catalogoCupones.sePermiteModificarElCupon(id_cupon);
    }
```

Comment: you want to add `catch` instead of callbacks?

Comment: no. i want to use the second form but it's not working.

Comment: You forgot the cardinal rule of Promises. `return`!!!! Elsewise it will never work.

Comment: but where i have to add the return?

Comment: From every function unless it _both_ is synchronous _and_ does not return a value.

Answer (score 1):

the word you're looking for is : [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

chain your promises like this :

```
var promise1 = estaElServicioDespachado(15)
var promise2 = sePermiteModificarElCupon(25)

Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
.then(function(){$state.go("barra.general.formularioCupon");})
.catch(reason => {          
    console.log(reason)
})
```

the example from MDN ( added a rejected promise to catch ) :

```js
let promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
let promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'foo');
});
let promise3 = 42;

let promise4 = Promise.reject('something went wrong in 4th promise');

// all goes well
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
.then(function(values) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
})
.catch((err) => { console.log(err) });

// an error thrown in the middle
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise4, promise3])
.then(function(values) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
})
.catch((err) => { console.log(err) });
```